# MEF for .NET 3.5 Signed Application

Tags: .net-3.5, mef, strongname

I'm trying to use [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28VS.100%29.aspx) in an assembly that builds against both .NET 4.0 and .NET 3.5. To my knowlege, MEF's `System.ComponentModel.CompositionModel` DLL is available within .NET 4.0, but not .NET 3.5.

I've tried downloading the latest MEF 1 release (preview 9) from the [CodePlex site](http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/40606), but I've run into trouble there as well. My application is signed, and thus required that external assemblies be referenced by their strong name. The MEF binaries from CodePlex don't appear to be strong-named.

Aside from building MEF binaries myself and signing, is there any trusted source where I download signed MEF .NET 3.5 binaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you discovered, the CTP binaries from CodePlex are not strong named.  There is no "official" version which is signed, as the only official release was the 4.0 build.

If you need MEF for 3.5 signed, you will likely need to just recompile and sign these yourself.